# Problem with creating multi workspaces in Vs Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created several .code-workspaces under a single working directory. After creating them I then opened individual .code-workspaces and noticed that files from other workspace are listed in the explorer pane. Why is that so?

I thought that the whole idea of a .code-workspace in VsCode is to group or isolate several related files  into a logical workspace so as to make it easier to work with them together. Should I be seeing other files that have already been added to other workspaces? Or is there something I did not do right when creating the .code-workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude files from workspace configure `settings."files.exclude"`

To show only selected folders, use `folders`. Note that the folders in tree (like `./packages/lib`) are still reachable from `.` tree

```
{
  "folders": [
    { "path": ".", "name": " ROOT" },
    { "path": "./packages/server", "name": " Server"},
    { "path": "./packages/client", "name": " Client" },
  ],
  "settings": {
    "files.exclude": {
      ".yarn": true,
      ".quasar": true
    },
  },
}
```